# Sharepoint 2010 alternate access mappings and HttpModule problem

Tags: alternate-access-mapping, debugging, http-module, web-application-zones

I have encountered an interesting problem recently.
I have a **HttpModule**, which i have added  in
 modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" node , by hand.

The main site collection is at http: //collection:81 .

If i access the site on the 81 port, the module works just fine. I can attach the visual studio **debugger** to the **wsp process**, and all works well.

The farm, however has an **alternate access mappings** set for the collection:81 the next alternate mappings: http: //mappedname , for example

The http module does not work there, it is **like it isn't loaded**.

I tried even to attach the **vs 2010 debugger to the wsp process**, but it doesn't want the enter in the **preinit** function of the **http module**, **like it doesn't even exist**.

I have tried to redo the situation in our test environments.

I set **an alternate mappings**, set the dns alias, and all worked well in the test environment.
The only difference is that in the test environment i tried to **add programaticaly the web.config modification**  on feature activated receiver, which worked on adding it, but **did not manage to remove** it on feature deactivation.

So, i am a little bit confused about this situation.
Any suggestion would be appreciated,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Is seems as if the module hasn't been added correctly to the web.config for the alternate zone.

Have you compared the web.config for the two zones?

Comment: Interesting what you say here. So the alternate zone has a different web.config? For example the sitecollection is on port 81 so i would find its web.config in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\81 . If i set a alternate access mappings will i have a different web.config to configure? Where would i find it?

Comment: If the additional url is made in the "right" way by extending the web application, then you'll have multiple IIS web sites with each their web.config

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have talked with the system administrator. He did not do it with web application extension. He says it should be the same configuration of the main site, but somehow the httpmodule does not get loaded. So, for what i see the web.config is created automatically at runtime for the alternate access mappings from the configuration database?